# Is there any Schema generator for XML input for Spark?

Tags: xml, apache-spark, schema

I have got big and complex XML files, which would be read from a Spark program. Writing the Schema manually would be a burdensome task. So, is there any existing tool, which can generate the Schema (StructType) from an XML file?

Comment: Google "XML schema generator".

Comment: I want one which generates StructType.

Comment: If you want to add information you can always edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [spark-xml](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) library to read xml files from spark. This will parse xml and give you a dataframe. You can use option `inferSchema` to infer an appropriate type.

Comment: No, I don't want that, I really want some tool to generate the Schema.